# screen scrape alphanumeric chars from picture

Tags: python, ocr, python-tesseract

I'm trying to find a way to screen scrape the letters and numbers (mainly numbers) from the attached picture.

[example picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6RHT.png)

In previous attempts, I've used pyocr and many other variations.

My question is, has any body found a way to scrape off numbers? Or how to train the pyocr algorithm to use custom data?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The folks at PyImageSearch have a TON of info about processing images in Python with OpenCV.

They even have a free blog post about using Tesseract OCR.  Though Tesseract can be a bit fussy about fonts, the good news is it looks like your text in the image should always be the same font, and perfectly aligned horizontally and vertically.

(disclaimer: I'm a student of theirs; but I don't work for them)
https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/09/17/opencv-ocr-and-text-recognition-with-tesseract/